# Can't find IDOK (1) in the custom UI! How to add a custom OK Button in NSIS?

Tags: user-interface, dialog, controls, custom-controls, nsis

Please Help ! In NSIS, I'm using

```
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW LicenseShow
```

then

```
Function LicenseShow

  ; New dialog for custom items
  nsDialogs::Create 1018
  Pop $0

  ; Accept button
  ${NSD_CreateButton} 373, 223, 50, 14 "Accept"  ; Can't find IDOK (1) in the custom UI! 

  ; Decline button
  ${NSD_CreateButton} 21, 223, 50, 14 "Decline"

  ; Picture
  ${NSD_CreateBitmap} 5 5 100% 100 "disclosure.bmp"
  Pop $0
  ${NSD_SetImage} $0 $PLUGINSDIR\image.bmp $ImageHandle

  ; Disclaimer
  nsDialogs::CreateControl /NOUNLOAD ${__NSD_Text_CLASS} ${DEFAULT_STYLES}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${ES_WANTRETURN}|${ES_MULTILINE} ${__NSD_Text_EXSTYLE} 5 220 660 115 ''
  Pop $1
  SendMessage $1 ${EM_SETREADONLY} 1 0
  SetCtlColors $1 0x000000 0xFFFFFF
  ${NSD_SetText} $1 "The license text"

  nsDialogs::Show
  ${NSD_FreeImage} $ImageHandle

FunctionEnd
```

**How do I tell that the Accept button has the IDOK on it ?**

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the id by calling `System::Call 'user32::SetWindowLong(i $myhwnd,i -12,i $mynewid)'` but what you really should be doing is setting up callback functions:

```
...
${NSD_CreateButton} ...
pop $0
${NSD_OnClick} $0 userclicked
...
Function userclicked
MessageBox mb_ok Hello
SendMessage $hwndparent ${WM_COMMAND} 1 0
FunctionEnd
```